# Submit button in custom admin form using ui component

Tags: uicomponent, adminform, submit-form

I want to write a custom module to export product data and I have a problem with a custom admin form using ui components. It will only have one simple select input with stores id and export button and here is the problem. I don't know how to use the button to submit this form. I'm following the [Magento 2 docs](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/button/#buttonaction-interface), but don't know what to put in the element called "targetName". I tried write something like this, but without success:

```
<item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">my_ui_component_filename.my_ui_component_filename</item>
```

When I write this I get an error in the console after I click the button:
[image]

My entire code for the button from the ui component .xml file:

```
<button name="export_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">productimportexport_importexport_form.productimportexport_importexport_form</item>
                        <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">export</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <displayAsLink>false</displayAsLink>
            <title translate="true">Export</title>
        </settings>
    </button>
```

I'm working on Magento 2.4.4. Can anyone help me? I searched google for a few hours but couldn't find the answer to my question.